# O que seria "morfar uma sandes"?

Tags: expressões, diferenças-transatlânticas

Acredito que poucos brasileiros já tenham ouvido essa expressão.  Ouvi na TV, recentemente, pela primeira vez. Não tenho a menor idéia do contexto em que foi usada, uma vez que eu não estava prestando atenção ao programa.  É bem provável, no entanto, que se trate de uma expressão lusitana pois ouvi na RTP.

Comment: não será "morfar uma sandes"? "morfar" significa "comer".

Comment: Tem a certeza que a expressão não tinha sentido literal? As duas palavras estão nos dicionários.

Comment: @Artefacto sim, "sandes".  Já corrigi.

Comment: @DanGetz  Se tinha sentido literal, pior ainda.  "morfar" e "sandes" definitivamente não fazem parte do vocabulário dos brasileiros, do analfabeto ao mais letrado.

Comment: Sem nenhuma base, mas _morfar_ me parece um aportuguesamento do verbo inglês _morph_. É um efeito usado em computação gráfica de transformar uma imagem em outra. Mas _sandes_ não consigo imaginar o que seria.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A expressão tem o significado das suas componentes:

> [**mor·far**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/morfar)
> (espanhol americano morfar)
> verbo transitivo
> *[Portugal, Informal]* Ingerir alimentos. = COMER
>
> [**san·des**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/sandes)
> (redução de sanduíche)
> substantivo feminino de dois números
> *[Informal]* Conjunto de duas fatias de pão intercaladas por um ou vários alimentos, geralmente em fatias (carne, fiambre, salame, queijo, tomate, ovo, etc.). = SANDE, SANDUÍCHE

Portanto, "morfar uma sandes" significa tão-somente "comer uma sanduíche".

Notas sobre as duas palavras:

- **morfar**, marcada como "informal" pelo Priberam é aquilo a que tecnicamente se chama uma palavra parva; só se usa em sentido jocoso (pelo menos no meu meio social).
- **sandes** é uma palavra bastante mais comum do que *sanduíche* em Portugal. Há pessoas que também usam "sande", que de facto está dicionarizada no Priberam, mas, pelo menos em Lisboa, é coisa rara. É mais incomum que do que "sanduíche" (e portanto muito mais do que "sandes").

Comment: Parece que "sanduiche" em Portugal é do gênero feminino.  Vivendo e aprendendo.

Comment: No Porto pode-se usar sem sentido jocoso: "hei malta, 'bora morfar?" Mas é pouco comum.